# How to import hierarchical folder style data

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, core-data, hierarchical-data

I have an array of objects that I need to iterate over and find/insert into a core data entity.  I just can't get my head around how to dive into albumParentFolders and see if they exist, if not add them to the entity albums.

I know it is some kind of recursive method that drills down into the albumParentFolders but due to how my AlbumObjects are structured cannot find a working solution.

So, my array of objects to import are like this

```
NSArray AlbumObjects
---------------------------------------
NSString * albumFolderName
NSString * albumDetailsTitle
NSString * albumDetailsURL
NSArray  * albumParentFolders (Array of (NSStrings *) of albumFolderNames used for the level in the tree this album lives in. Can be nil for a root folder)
```

I need to first search core data and if not found insert the albumFolderName into a Core Data Entity called albums.  Then using the auto generated class for the album entity, insert a new details object for that folder.  e.g. [newFolder addDetailsObject:newDetails]  Also, albumFolderName is not unique in core data as the albumFolderName could be listed multiple times but in different parent folders.

```
Entity: albums
-------------------------------------
Attribute: folderName
-------------------------------------
Relationship: albumDetails <------>> Entity : details (For adding multiple albumDetailsTitle and albumDetailsURL)
Relationship: parent     <<-------
Relationship: subGroups          |
                     ^           |
                     ------------
```

The album folders are eventually displayed in a treeview using NSOutlineView and IB bindings.  This part already works.

If anybody could advise on how to iterate the AlbumObjects, specifically  drilling into albumParentFolders so that the entire folder structure can be stored in the entity I would be hugely grateful.

SDK needs to support OSX 10.7+

Comment: Is `albumParentFolders` a full path? AlbumFolderNames are not unique and you only insert when not found?

Comment: albumParentFolders is either nil or the full path which may look something like [0]=@"General"  [1]=@"July 2016"  [2]=@"Keep"   albumFolderName would be @"Keep" in that case.  albumFolderName could also be nil, suggesting it has no folder therefore a root detail item.



What I am finding hard is that the next array object could be in a similar folder like [0]=@"New Import"  [1]=@"July 2016"  [2]=@"Keep" so I need to kind of find parent of parent of parent to validate it either exists or not.  I guess this is the recursive part again which I cannot fathom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start at the root, follow the tree and create missing branches.

Pseudo code:

```
album = root
if (albumParentFolders != nil) {
    parentAlbum = root
    for (folder in albumParentFolders) {
        album = find folder in parentAlbum.subGroups
        if (album not found) {
            album = insert new album
            album.folderName = folder
            album.parent = parentAlbum
        }
        parentAlbum = album
    }
}
add details to album
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your example was just what I needed to get me on the right track :D  I now have it working.

Comment: I thought it was going too well.  I still have an issue, for example I import albums and details which have folders  (ABC / July / Keep) and then import a different set of albums with the folders (DEF / July / Keep) it will add the new album details for /July and /Keep into the ABC folders.  I do not want that to happen, I create a new folder on every import and want all new albums to go in there.  Any ideas?

Comment: `find folder in subGroups of parentAlbum` isn't a fetchRequest. It searches for `folder` in `parentAlbum.subGroups`. I've updated my answer. Are ABC and DEF subGroups of root or do you create a new root on every import?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for getting back.  I create a new root on every import (based on datetime string).  I understand what you mean, I have it working again now thanks for your help Willeke.  Will send you a free app code when this version gets approved :)  Hmm, just discovered there is no PM feature on here!